# Ping Script with filter

Tags: bash, perl

I have a text file with host names and IP addresses like so (one IP and one host name per row). The IP addresses and host names can be separated by a spaces and/or a pipe, and the host name may be before or after the IP address

```
10.10.10.10 HW-DL11_C023
11.11.11.11 HW-DL11_C024
10.10.10.13 | HW-DL12_C023
11.11.11.12 | HW-DL12_C024
HW-DL13_C023 11.10.10.10 
HW-DL13_C024 21.11.11.11 
HW-DL14_C023 | 11.10.10.10 
HW-DL14_C024 | 21.11.11.11
```

The script below should be able to ping hosts with a common denominator e.g. DL13 (there are two devices and it will ping only those two). What am I doing wrong, as I simply can`t make it work?

The script is in the same directory as the data; I don`t get errors, and everything is formatted. The server is Linux.

```
pingme () {
hostfile="/home/rex/u128789/hostfile.txt"
IFS= mapfile -t  hosts < <(cat $hostfile)
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    match=$(echo "$host" | grep -o "\-$1_" | sed 's/-//' | sed 's/_//')
    if [[ "$match" = "$1" ]]; then
        hostname=$(echo "$host" | awk '{print $2}')
        ping -c1 -W1 $(echo "$host" | awk '{print $1}') > /dev/null
        if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
            echo "$hostname is alive"
        elif [[ $? = 1 ]]; then
            echo "$hostname is dead"
        fi
    fi
done
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include what output you're getting currently. Also, consider adding some more echo statements to confirm it's getting as far as you think it is. e.g. first thing in the loop, the result of the match, etc. That should lead you to where it is breaking down quickly.

Comment: Hi David, not sure how can I answer this , but in fact I don`t get any output . It does not run and does not produce an error.Something is missing and me not being so keen on coding , I just don`t know how to debug it in such scenario.

Comment: Two great suggestions: David Hempy's `echo` (which apparently failed to echo *ANYTHING*) and Mike Q's a) `First, check that your input and output is working correctly`, then b) `instead of a function first try to make it work as a script`.  PLEASE TRY REMOVING `ping() { ...}`: just make it a "script" (instead of a "scription function") and see what happens.

Comment: @REX kindly have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these two lines to your code:

```
pingme () {
hostfile="/home/rex/u128789/hostfile.txt"
IFS= mapfile -t  hosts < <(cat $hostfile)
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    echo "Hostname: $host"                      # <-------- ADD THIS LINE -------
    match=$(echo "$host" | grep -o "\-$1_" | sed 's/-//' | sed 's/_//')
    echo "...matched with $match"               # <-------- ADD THIS LINE -------
    if [[ "$match" = "$1" ]]; then
        hostname=$(echo "$host" | awk '{print $2}')
        ping -c1 -W1 $(echo "$host" | awk '{print $1}') > /dev/null
        if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
            echo "$hostname is alive"
        elif [[ $? = 1 ]]; then
            echo "$hostname is dead"
        fi
    fi
done
}
```

Then when you run it, you should see a list of your  hosts, at least.

- If you don't then you're not reading your file successfully.
- If you do, there's a problem in your per-host logic.

Congratulations! You've divided your problem into two smaller problems. Once you know which half has the problem, keep dividing the problem in half until the smallest possible problem is staring you in the face. You'll probably know the solution at that point. If not, add your findings to the question and we'll help out from there.

Comment: No output in any of the test lines :    
                                                                                                          
    REX@Lenovo-PC:/mnt/c/Users/REX$ ./pingme.sh
    REX@Lenovo-PC:/mnt/c/Users/REX$ ./pingme.sh DL11
    REX@Lenovo-PC:/mnt/c/Users/REX$ ./pingme.sh DL12
    REX@Lenovo-PC:/mnt/c/Users/REX$ ./pingme.sh DL13
    REX@Lenovo-PC:/mnt/c/Users/REX$ ./pingme.sh DL14
    REX@Lenovo-PC:/mnt/c/Users/REXi$

Comment: Excellent! Now you know the for loop is never entered. Now start inserting some echos between each of the lines above, and see which it the first one that doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: BTW, where are you actually calling pingme() ? Can you edit your question to show that? Just defining a function won't run it.

Answer (score 1):

The original code doesn't handle the pipe separator or the possibly reversed hostname and IP address in the input file.  It also  makes a lot of unnecessary use of external programs (`grep`, `sed`, ...).

Try this:

```
# Enable extended glob patterns - e.g. +(pattern-list)
shopt -s extglob

function pingme
{
    local -r host_denom=$1

    local -r hostfile=$HOME/u128789/hostfile.txt

    local ipaddr host tmp
    # (Add '|' to the usual characters in IFS)
    while IFS=$'| \t\n' read -r ipaddr host ; do
        # Swap host and IP address if necessary
        if [[ $host == +([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9]) ]] ; then
            tmp=$host
            host=$ipaddr
            ipaddr=$tmp
        fi

        # Ping the host if its name contains the "denominator"
        if [[ $host == *-"$host_denom"_* ]] ; then
            if ping -c1 -W1 -- "$ipaddr" >/dev/null ; then
                printf '%s is alive\n' "$host"
            else
                printf '%s is dead\n' "$host"
            fi
        fi
    done < "$hostfile"

    return 0
}

pingme DL13
```

The final line (call the `pingme` function) is just an example, but it's essential to make the code do something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No results unfortunately . I will have a go on 2 other Linux systems to see if it would even budge. Surely must be something I am doing wrong- saving the file as .sh/ calling it as ./pingme.sh  or version of linux , or text file. Will explore.But at least produces an error = >  ./pingme.sh DL14
./pingme.sh: line 5: $/mnt/c/Users/REX/hostfile.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: The error message refers to a file `$/mnt/c/Users/REX/hostfile.txt`.  With the leading `$`, that does't look like a valid path.  It's not the filename in the example code.  I guess that something went wrong when the code was modified.  Also, the error occurred on line 5, and the redirection in the example code is much later in the source file.  It looks like something other than the example code is in 'pingme.sh'.  Check the contents of 'pingme.sh', and particularly check the path to 'hostfile.txt'.

Answer (score 1):

REX, you need to be more specific about your what IP's you are trying to get from this example. You also don't ping enough times IMO and your script is case sensitive checking the string (not major). Anyway,

First, check that your input and output is working correctly, in this example I'm just reading and printing, if this doesn't work fix permissions etc :

```
file="/tmp/hostfile.txt"
while IFS= read -r line ;do
        echo $line
done < "${file}"
```

Next, instead of a function first try to make it work as a script, in this example I manually set "match" to DL13, then I read each line (like before) and (1) match on $match, if found I remove the '|', and then read the line into an array of 2. if the first array item is an a IP (contains periods) set it as the IP the other as hostname, else set the opposite. Then run the ping test.

```
# BASH4+ Example:
file="/tmp/hostfile.txt"
match="dl13"
while IFS= read -r line ;do

        # -- check for matching string (e.g. dl13 --
        [[ "${line,,}" =~ "${match,,}" ]] || continue

        # -- We found a match, split out host/ip into vars --
        line=$(echo ${line//|})
        IFS=' ' read -r -a items <<< "$line"
        if [[ "${items[0]}" =~ '.' ]] ;then
            host="${items[1]}" ; ip="${items[0]}"
        else
            host="${items[0]}" ; ip="${items[1]}"
        fi

        # -- Ping test --
        ping -q -c3 "${ip}" > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] ;then
            echo "$host is alive!"
        else
            echo "$host is toast!"
        fi

done < "${file}"
```